# how do i make the 5th and 6th li a left aligned using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying bootstrap to make a navbar .I am struggling to make the login and logout right aligned .how could i do it???i have uploaded the html and css code

**Html code:**

```
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log-out</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log-in</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Inverted Navbar</h3>
  <p>An inverted navbar is black instead of gray.</p>
</div>

</body>
```

**CSS code:**

```
 <style>
  .navbar navbar-inverse .nav navbar-nav ul li a:nth-child(5):nth-child(6)
  {
      background-color:green;
      float :right;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the`<li>` that's 5th and 6th and not `<a>`. Also, your selector is wrong in CSS (there's no `<navbar-inverse>` tag, which is what you meant). Kindly correct it:

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse ul.nav.navbar-nav li:nth-child(5) a,
.navbar.navbar-inverse ul.nav.navbar-nav li:nth-child(6) a {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse ul.nav.navbar-nav li:nth-child(5) a,
.navbar.navbar-inverse ul.nav.navbar-nav li:nth-child(6) a {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log-out</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log-in</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the nth `li`, not the nth `a`, because there is always only one `a`.

```css
.navbar-nav > li:nth-child( 5 ),
.navbar-nav > li:nth-child( 6 ) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Log-out</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Log-in</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you need to do several things to get this working:

1) Use float:right; on the 5th and 6th Li elements, 
2) In your case it is floating right within the UL but the UL is not the full width of the nav bar. To correct this adjust the UL to be full width of the nav bar.

I have implemented the solutions users have suggested above on Code Pen and none work in your situation until you adjust the width of the UL, take a look:

```
.nav{
  width:100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvZXJM